# Could exotic baryons be stable inside exotic stars?

Tags: neutron-stars, baryons

Neutrons are stable inside a neutron star because beta decay doesn't release enough energy to send the proton and electron up to the Fermi energy. Could this principle apply to baryons that have charm, strange, and bottom quarks? I'm talking about stars made of degenerate baryons, not quark matter.

Comment: Search term: [strange star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_star)

Comment: In response to your edit: I have read literature about kaons and/or lambda baryons in secular equilibrium in dense stars, but it’s been a long time.